# Unable to add user using useradd

Tags: linux, centos, ldap

Attempting to add a (non-existant) user to my CentOS system is returning `useradd: user example exists`. I can successfully manually add the user to /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow, but that workaround is A Bad Thing. The user exists in LDAP, but PAM isn't using LDAP for authentication. Adding other users works fine. I'm stumped.

ETA:

```
[root ~]# userdel example
userdel: error deleting password entry
userdel: error deleting shadow password entry
[root ~]# useradd example
useradd: user example exists
[root ~]# su example
bash-3.2$ whoami
example
bash-3.2$ groups example
example : Users
bash-3.2$ cd
bash: cd: /home/example: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/62743/what-files-are-created-modified-when-adding-a-user-useradd-in-linux

Comment: What did you get if you try `su example`?

Comment: @Khaled It drops me into a standard bash shell. `pwd` shows location as `/root`. `whoami` shows as the user, `groups example` shows that they're a member of the Users group

Comment: useradd aliased?

Comment: `[root@ ~]# which useradd` `/usr/sbin/useradd`, not aliased.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you include LDAP in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (for example `passwd: files ldap`  or   `passwd:compat  passwd_compat:ldap`, etc.) it is enough for `getent passwd` and thus for `useradd` to see LDAP entries.

Both utilities have nothing to do with PAM, and happily recognize LDAP entries even if PAM knows nothing about LDAP.

By the way, if you have `nscd` running, remember to restart it after you change `nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Goodness, my understanding of linux auth is clearly lacking. I didn't know that was a thing. That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete user and adding him again after stopping the sssd service (I had no idea it was on the server)

```
service sssd stop
deluser -f MyUser
```